# "Established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine" (IIS)

Tags: c#, iis, webclient

I'm trying to configure IIS 7.5 so that it can serve large (400mb) files via HTTP. The client is a C# client using `WebClient.DownloadFile()` (*basically wrapping an HTTP GET request*).

However when downloading, I occasionally get the error from the client:

> An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Anything I can do in either the client or IIS to prevent this error?

Comment: Did you check if you have configured any firewall in your machine.

Comment: No software firewall on my machine, or on the server. No hardware firewall on my side either (server is hosted, so I dont know about the server side).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much digging around, it looks like a dodgy internet connection on my side. All clients on my site disconnect at the same time, but clients on another site stay connected. Unfortunately the internet router that I have here doesnt have any connectivity logs (its a top-of-the-range linksys.. go figure) so it wasnt easy to see what the problem was.

Comment: This also occurred to us from a bad NIC or network driver on our new ESX host. Switching EXS hosts fixed the issue. Definitely related to flaky network connectivity.